# Shared rent - home office expenses in partnership

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction

I rent a 2 bed flat with my girlfriend (3 rooms inc combined living room and kitchen). The total rent is £1581. My girlfriend pays £650 and I pay £931 rent. The second bedroom I use exclusively as a home office. We agreed the rent split partly on the basis that I would be the only one using the office.

On what basis should I calculate the expense of my office?

The proportionate share of my rent - 1/3 of £931  = £310

The proportionate share of the total rent (the "real" value of the office) - 1/3 of £1581 = £527

The difference between mine and my girlfriend's rent (kind of arbitrary) - £281

Comment: This might help. https://www.crunch.co.uk/knowledge/tax/working-from-home-what-expenses-claim/ . Yours is a bit complicated though, what does your accountant opine on this arrangement. I would prefer to go to an accountant rather than here.

Comment: It is *probably fair to say* in *general principle* that if you choose a *reasonable* value with a *reasonable* (written down for your own record) rationale behind it, you should be ok submitting that amount. Theoretically, in the abstract, if some Tax Official was grilling you on the issue, would your statements and position be reasonable and logical? If so, away you go.

Comment: In Germany I would go for 1/3 of total rent. You could just as well be the lone tenant or decide to rent the other room to somebody else. Does not affect the base price. Also in Germany I would be bound to a maximum deduction for a home-office or have a separate entrance.